# SELECTING TWO COLUMN IN A TABLE FROM MY DATABASE

Tags: php

Hello guys am new to STACK OVERFLOW .. I JUST HAVE A question on this.. I want to select two column in my database table .. One for WHERE and the other one is for what am searching for

Comment: And what have you tried today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome bro, you can not do it like that, when you select two columns then it will back in your query , on (where) command or sql  you can search by any one of the columns , but you can select the columns that you want to see in the result .

this is example for sql query :

```
SELECT real_easte.category, real_easte.yard FROM `real_easte` WHERE number_of_floor = 2
```

where is select this two columns ( real_easte.category, real_easte.yard ) and search by (number_of_floor)

i hope that clear idea for you